# Group the logging inside a java servlet per user / per request

Tags: java, servlets, logging, slf4j

I have a simple servlet that does some calculations, and logs the intermediate results to a file using slf4j as the facade and a simple logging binder (also from slf4j) to log to the file. This works fine, but when multiple users are sending requests simultaneously, their logs get interwoven with each other. Below is a dummy example to show the problem: the logging from both user alice and bob gets mixed up:

```
log: phase1 of user alice
log: phase2 of user alice
log: phase1 of user bob
log: phase3 of user alice
log: phase2 of user bob
log: phase3 of user bob
...
```

This is really troublesome if the amount of users involved and the complexity of the log statements increases.

A possible solution is to create a logfile for each user, and when a request enters by user X (this can be detected by my code), append it to logfile X. The problem is I don't see how to do this with simple logging. Is is possible, and if not, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You could store entries for each user phase in some structure and then log all phases as single log entry at the end of last phase, or immediately when/if an error happens.

Comment: Although this is would yield the desired result (namely, have grouped block of logs in the logfile), it is not trivial to create some sort of "cache" where every class can store log entries for each user until the last phase occurs. With nontrivial, I mean it complicates/polutes the source code beyond just writing "logger.log(text)". I'll look into this if no other alternatives exist, thanks!

Comment: Just an idea how this could be implemented. You could have simple StringBuilder which could be wraped with some custom Log Builder class. Each phase calls this LogBuilder.Append(String logEntry, optionaly phase name) and then final phase calls LogBuilder.log() which logs content of StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the "MDC" (Mapped Diagnostic Context) class in SLF4J (other logging frameworks also support this).

It allows you to set custom logging context data and then you can get that data to appear in your messages.

For example, you could do...

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;

...
    private static final USER_NAME_MDC_KEY = "USRKEY";

    servlet method {
        MDC.put(USER_NAME_MDC_KEY, user.getUserId());

        ...rest of logic...

    }
```

If you have a pattern set up like this...

```
        <PatternLayout pattern="[UID=%X{USRKEY}] %d{HH:mm} [%t] %-level %c{1} - %m%n" />
```

...then each line in your log will contain...

```
[UID=<whatever has been set in the MDC>]
```

You could then GREP your logs for the particular user Id in order to get the messages logged just for them.

(I think this is sort of what you wanted, I might be wrong!)

Comment: Instead of putting this code directly in your servlet, you might be able to set up a "Filter" to do this for you (if you can get access to the User ID from the request that is)

Comment: Excellent! So basicly you're saying, put it all in one file, but filter the file based on id when viewing the logs. Two small questions though: how do you setup the pattern (where, in which file?) and how do you "GREP" on a logfile.txt on a windows machine?

Comment: @user1884155 The pattern I used in this example works when SLF4J is using Log4J2 "under the hood". What logging framework are you using? If it is log4j, then you can provide a log4j.xml configuration file to do this (loads of examples of this on the net). On Windows, you can use "findstr" in place of grep

Comment: Atm I use a simple logger because there was no need for anything else, but log4j it will become :) There are indeed tons of examples available on the web for setting up and configuring it, thanks!